# Clientside Heart Vote

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute, voting-system

Is there a way to implement a simple Heart vote(just +1 vote with counter without ability to vote more than once) using only Javascript / jQuery and HTML5 data attributes, other HTML5 APIs, without any serverside stuff?

Comment: how would you keep track of the votes without a resource that is accessible by all users (i.e. a server)?

Comment: I don't really know how to do that. I'm just learning :|

Comment: the question was supposed to be somewhat rhetorical. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` to record that client has voted. Something like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('voted', true);
```

To check if client voted before:

```
var voted = localStorage.get item('voted');
```

Update:

As you need a counter, you may try one of BAAS (backend-as-a-service) services, such as parse.com or kinvey.com

Comment: That wouldn't work to show the total number of +1 votes because it would be stored locally on the clients.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. You need a server to store all the responses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store it in some type of database. So if you don't have any server side code that does this you need to find a service that will do it for you. (I don't know if one exists but  i wouldn't be surprised if there did).